# accessing Putty outputstream with pywinauto

Tags: python, putty, paramiko, pywinauto

I am trying to automate a ssh connection with pywinauto. I am connecting via Putty to my server and can execute commands. However, I need to get the output of the Putty to verify what exactly is going on the server. Below you find my example code so far which I find on stackoverflow:

```
import time
import sys

app = Application ().Start (cmd_line=u'putty -ssh root@host')
putty = app.PuTTY
putty.Wait ('ready')
time.sleep (1)
putty.TypeKeys ("cd{SPACE}/")
putty.TypeKeys ("{ENTER}")
time.sleep (1)
putty.TypeKeys ("ls")
putty.TypeKeys ("{ENTER}")
```

I need a function that gives me the outputstream of the putty window. Something like:

```
stream = putty.ReadConsoleOutputStream()
lines = stream.readLines()
```

I tried it with:

```
print(putty.window_text())
```

but it only gives me the title of the window back. I have heard about paramiko but since the connection is passwordless, I couldn't access it via paramiko because i couldn't find a way to connect it without a password.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is planned in pywinauto: [issue 492](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/492), but with low priority. Feel free to help with the implementation.